# Помогите подобрать компоненты и немного разобраться с Vue

Tags: vue.js

Всем привет. Начал изучать Vue и перевожу один из проектов на него, чтобы сразу практиковать прочтённую документацию.

Вот [пример](https://y.co/) сайта чем-то похожего на те, которые я делаю.

**Есть несколько моментов, с которыми не могу определиться, надеюсь поможет кто-нибудь разобраться:**

1. Использовать ли Nuxt для старта проектов или же использовать vue init webpack ?
2. Как в Nuxt делать transition для отдельного элемента? В документации Nuxtjs описаны transition для страниц. К примеру нужно сделать так, чтобы когда страница(route) появлялась из opacity (это я сделал), то текст на странице выезжал слева, чтобы делать интерактивные сайты...нажал на перехо между страницами заголовок и картинка уехали, а на следующей странице приехали.
3. Какой слайдер для vue посоветуете и как его встроить в Nuxt? Пробовал встроить в Nuxt вот этот слайдер github.com/hilongjw/vue-slide, но выдаёт ошибку рендера, подключал глобально по документации.
4. Какой выбрать компонент для модальных окон на vue.
5. Как лучше выкладывать сайты как в примере в начале моего вопроса, собирать как статический проект?

Всем заранее спасибо за ответы.

Answer (score 2):

Хотите изучать vue и понимать что к чему, думаю поступайте так (так поступил я и не жалею):

1. начните со сборки проекта на webpack
2. компоненты, в которых у меня возникает необходимость при работе в vue: `vue-resource` (`axios` для тех же целей), `vuex`,
   `vue-router`
3. чтение документации с каждым разом вносит все больше
   ясностей
4. сторонние библиотеки подключаю через npm и просто делаю
   `require` или `import Name from './test-library'` в корневом файле
   (называю его с изучения laravel `app.js`)

Думаю освоив на минимальном уровне все и создав пару десяток примеров, можете смело использовать Nuxt.

Для модальных окон использую bootstrap 3 и всегда устраивает

Comment: Спасибо большое за ответ. Поставлю +1, когда будут баллы.